# Composer Failed to decode response: zlib_decode()

Tags: php

I'm trying to install crudkit.com. This is my composer.json:

```
{
    "description" : "The CodeIgniter framework",
    "name" : "codeigniter/framework",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.2.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.1.*"
    }

}
```

After that, I run the composer using:

```
$ sudo php composer.phar install
```

But I got error like this:

```
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Failed to decode response: zlib_decode(): data error
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info
```

Anyone know how to solve it?

UPDATE:
I have try to composer diagnose, and I got this:

```
Checking composer.json: FAIL
The version field is present, it is recommended to leave it out if the package is published on Packagist.
Checking platform settings: FAIL
The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.
```

Answer (score 0):

try to update composer as follow.

> sudo composer clear-cache

add this line to composer.json

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packagist.org"
    },
    { "packagist": false }
],
```

and then

> sudo composer update

Answer (score 0):

Writing the given lines in your composer.json files Hope it helps someone as it does to me.
Then run composer update
    "repositories": [
            {
                "type": "composer",
                "url": "https://packagist.org"
            },
            { "packagist": false }
        ]